# How to sync only specific folders from Google Drive with “Backup and Sync?”

Tags: google-backup-and-sync

I have a folder for my web development projects on Google Drive (currently empty, not in use yet) and I want to install the Backup and Sync to my Windows computer so that I don't have to drag and drop all the time the files to upload.

I've read that the Backup and Sync app syncs folders from the computer (Desktop, Documents, Pictures) by default and I don't want that. I don't want to sync any folder from my PC/Laptop to Google Drive, I just want to bring in the folders from Drive to my PC/Laptop.

Is it possible to deny all the user folder syncs and just sync the folders from Drive?

I already had a disaster couple of years back when OneDrive (which comes with Windows 10 by default and instantly activates on first boot) tried to sync my user folders and I lost some files when I cancelled it and had to use restore point to get the files back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can deny all the user folder syncs and just sync the folders from Drive to PC /Laptop. You can refer to the following steps to set up:

1. Download and Install Backup and Sync. Make sure to grab the appropriate download for your device (Mac or PC).
2. If you previously had the Google Drive app installed, Backup and Sync should automatically log in to your Google Account. If not, you’ll need to log in. After that, a quick splash screen will let you know what the app is all about: backing up your stuff. Click “Got it” to move into the app.
3. Now, on the main page of the app, select Google Drive section, which is second in the list. Tick the box next to "Sync My Drive to this computer" and choose "Sync only these folders" and select Which folders you want to sync from Google Drive to PC/Laptop. After selecting, click on "OK" to save your settings. 
   Generally, if you want to stop Google Drive sync, you can disable "Sync My Drive to this computer" feature directly. And sometimes, Google Drive may stop sync for unknown reasons, but don't be panic, you can try to fix [Google Drive stopped sync](https://cloud.ubackup.com/articles/google-drive-stopped-syncing-6688.html) error with effective methods.

Comment: Yeah, I already figured this on my own, but forgot that I asked about it here.

Comment: Glad your problem has been solved！

Comment: And now? Backup and Sync was unified with Drive... Is there a workaround?